# React state still undefined after fetching inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

In my react app, I am making a request to an API inside `useEffect`. Once the promise is returned, I am setting `state`. I then need to use that state to subscribe to a websocket, but state is coming back as undefined so for now I am just logging the state. I only want to do this on initial page load. How can I make an API request, save that information to state, then use that state to do something all on initial page load only?

```
 const fetchInstruments = () => {
  return axios
    .post('http://localhost:5050/0/public/AssetPairs')
    .then(({ data }) => {
      return data.result
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}

function App() {
  const [instruments, setInstruments] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInstruments().then((fetchedInstruments) => {
      setInstruments(fetchedInstruments)
    })
    .then(()=> console.log(instruments)) //this is undefined
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: State changes in React are not synchronous, they are batched as a performance optimization. Your components will rerender with the correct state after you set it.

Comment: `setInstrument` is not sync

Answer (score 2):

if I were in your place, I would not use the state to subscribe to a websocket, I will use the result of the HTTP request

checkout this

```
function App() {
  const [instruments, setInstruments] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInstruments().then((fetchedInstruments) => {
      setInstruments(fetchedInstruments);
      return fetchedInstruments;        // <====== 
    })
    .then((fetchedInstruments) => {
         console.log(fetchedInstruments);
         //TODO : handle websocket subscription 
    }) 
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: I proposed almost the same thing. But is it necessary to make the websocket subscription in an other promise ? Why not doing it directly in the first promise, when we fetched the instruments? Is it to avoid nested call I assume

Comment: Both answers seem to work, why do you want to avoid nested call?

Comment: Just so the code looks less messy I guess

Answer (score 1):

You can just make your second API call when you fetched your instruments:

```
function App() {
  const [instruments, setInstruments] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInstruments().then((fetchedInstruments) => {
      setInstruments(fetchedInstruments)
      secondApiCall(fetchedInstruments); // You can do your second API call here
    })
  }, [])
}
```